# How to simplify basic mathematical expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Assuming g is real, how can I simplify the following:
$$(2-2^{-g}) + 2^{-(g+1)}$$

I know the simplification ends with:
$$2-2^{-(g+1)}$$

I just don't understand how to manipulate the equation.

Comment: *Mathematica* performs this simplification immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that
$$
(2 - 2^{-g}) + 2^{-(g+1)} = 2 - 2^{-g} + 2^{-g} \cdot 2^{-1} = 2 - 2^{-g} + 2^{-g} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 2 - 2^{-g}\left(1 - \frac{1}{2}\right).
$$
Hence
$$
(2 - 2^{-g}) + 2^{-(g+1)} = 2 - 2^{-g} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 2 - 2^{-g} \cdot 2^{-1} = 2 - 2^{-g-1} = 2 - 2^{-(g+1)},
$$
which is the result you were looking for.

Comment: looking over the first part of this, how can we get the $(1-\frac{1}{2})$ on the end of the first line? Is the $2^{-g}$ just factored out?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It might be even more explicit if we write $2 - 2^{-g} + 2^{-g} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 2 - 2^{-g} \cdot 1 - 2^{-g} \cdot \frac{-1}{2} = 2 - 2^{-g} ( 1 - \frac{1}{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

$$2-2^{-g}+2^{-(g+1)}= 2-2\cdot 2^{-(g+1)}+2^{-(g+1)}= 2-2^{-(g+1)}$$